# Safari + Jquery + Replace

Tags: jquery, replace, safari

Couldn't find any answers to this question:

How come this works everywhere except in Safari?

```
var img = $(this).css('background-image');
img = img.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `img` is before you perform the `replace()` on it?

Comment: What is the result in Safari? Can you show us an example?

Comment: verified. doesn't work in safari. gets the background image but doesn't trim the url() part like it does it ff, chrome. why don't you people give it a try before you downvote.

Comment: demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5xLkv2p5/

Comment: @RobertParham So what returns `$(this).css('background-image')` in Safari? `why don't you people give it a try before you downvote` That's not the problem. OP should be more specific regarding his issue, just like answering in question itself the previous question i asked. Because i don't think the issue is regarding `replace()` method but the computed css property which is obviously different on Safari. I could be wrong because i cannot test it (on Safari)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work in Safari is because the computed styles in safari don't include the optional quotes, therefore the pattern `url("` and `")` won't match anything. You can solve this by removing the quotes separately.

```
img.replace('url(', '')
.replace(')', '')
.replace("'", "") // single quotes
.replace('"', ''); // dbl quotes
```

This should work in all browsers

Comment: Now i'm wondering why OP didn't just checked it... :) Anyway you get my vote ;)

Comment: Thank your very much, Robert.

A. Wolff: I ask because I couldn't figure it out myself. I always try before asking. Robert obviously got what I meant and was quite helpful.